# mySQL sytem to grade marks reading from a database and choosing subject of two

Tags: database

trying to develop a system to assign grades to students. The system reads marks from my database, and assigns a grade after getting average of scores. 
Used case statements, keep throwing errors. So i tried if statements but its giving me issues.  Someone know a better way to do it?

```
delimiter //

create function assign_grade(v_idnumber int)
returns varchar(50) deterministic
begin

  declare v_marks1 varchar(50);
  declare v_marks2 varchar(20);
  declare phyz varchar(50);
  declare Chem varchar(50);
  declare grade varchar(50);



  set phyz = (select Physics from marks where Sid=v_idnumber);
  set Chem=(select Chemistry from marks where Sid=v_idnumber);

  if(phyz>Chem)
  begin
   set v_marks1=(select(English+Kisw+Math+Physics+Bio+Business+Geog+Cre)/8 from marks where Sid=v_idnumber);

   if (v_marks1>= 80 && v_marks1<=100) then
            set grade ='A'; 
                else if (v_marks1>=60&& v_marks1<=79) 
                    set grade='B';
                else if (v_marks1>=40&& v_marks1<=59)
                    set grade ='C';
                else if (v_marks1>=30&& v_marks1<=49)
                    set grade ='D';
                else if (v_marks1>=0&& v_marks1<=29)
                   set grade ='E';  
                else
                    set grade = 'Failed Miserably';

             end if
             end if
             end if
             end if
             end if

             return grade;

    end;

     if(Chem>phyz)
           begin
            set v_marks2=(select(English+Kisw+Math+Chemistry+Bio+Business+Geog+Cre)/8 from marks where Sid=v_idnumber);
       if (v_marks2>= 80 && v_marks2<=100) then
            set grade ='A'; 
                else if (v_marks2>=60&& v_marks2<=79) 
                    set grade='B';
                else if (v_marks2=40&& v_marks2<=59)
                    set grade ='C';
                else if (v_marks2>=30&& v_marks2<=49)
                    set grade ='D';
                else if (v_marks2>=0&& v_marks2<=29)
                   set grade ='E';  
                else
                    set grade = 'Failed Miserably';

             end if
             end if
             end if
             end if
             end if

             end;

             return grade;



  //
```

Comment: what errors did you get? at the moment the phyz>chem and the chem>phyz seem to do exactly the same??

Comment: +1 for the "what errors" :p Yes, code is duplicate, but the just one difference is when he set v_marks1 and v_marks2 (physics was replace by chemestry)...

Answer (score 0):

For start, You want just optimize your function

(I'm not expert in your language (I think is Vb right?) ):

```
set phyz = (select Physics from marks where Sid=v_idnumber);
set Chem = (select Chemistry from marks where Sid=v_idnumber);

if(phyz>Chem)
    set v_marks=(select(English+Kisw+Math+Physics+Bio+Business+Geog+Cre)/8 from marks where Sid=v_idnumber);
else /*if (Chem > phyz) I comment the "if" for treatment where chem > phyz and Chem == phyz */
    set v_marks=(select(English+Kisw+Math+Chemistry+Bio+Business+Geog+Cre)/8 from marks where Sid=v_idnumber);
end if

/* You have just one same treatment for all types (phyz > chem ; chem >phyz, etc...) 
   When you optimize you code, verify your code isn't duplicate :-) 
*/ 

if (v_marks>= 80 && v_marks<=100)
    set grade = 'A'; 
else if (v_marks>=60 && v_marks<=79) 
    set grade = 'B';
else if (v_marks>=40 && v_marks<=59)
    set grade = 'C';
else if (v_marks>=30 && v_marks<=49)
    set grade = 'D';
else if (v_marks>=0 && v_marks<=29)
    set grade = 'E';  
else
    set grade = 'Failed Miserably';
end if

return grade;
```

Comment: its supposed to pick the one with more marks between physics and chem. the first phyz>chem, or if chem>phys, for computation.

Comment: The main error it keeps throwing is on set v>marks1= select .....
the select works ok,but not when put together.

Comment: @user1583040 : you say "but not when put together" , but if phyz>Chem, Chem will never > phyz, maybe I don't understand what you want (sorry, my english is bad) .
So, I look at one error in my code, we have a treatment when chem > phyz, when phyz > chem, but if chem = phyz, we have no treatment...

I have replace "else in" in my code...

Comment: i mean, when i have to pass set v_marks1=(select(English+Kisw+Math+Physics+Bio+Business+Geog+Cre)/8 from marks where Sid=v_idnumber);
i want the result of calculation to be stored in v_marks1. Somehow it does not allow.
.....and you're english is fine. thanks